# Visual Studio 15 with Unity Project Target Framework Not Installed

Tags: c#, winforms, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2019

I want try [Unity](https://unity.com/) `UnityDownloadAssistant-2018.3.12f1` with Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 Version: `14.0.25431.01` Update 3 and Microsoft .NET Framework Version `4.7.03056`.

I've installed [Personal](https://store.unity.com/download?ref=personal) `.exe` by `C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor` path *File version:* `2018.3.12.64867` *Product version:* `2018.3.12.9108835` on Windows 10 pro OS.

In `Edit/Preferences/External`: `Visual Studio 2015` and `Editor Attaching` is already checked and selected.

When I click basic demo script `.cs` file from Unity project, `load filed`,  does not loads  project folders and files to VS. Before  attempt to load, shows    message:

[image]

> C:\Users\User\Documents\New Unity Project\Assembly-CSharp.csproj :
>   error  : Project 'Assembly-CSharp' could not be opened because the
>   Visual C# 2015 compiler could not be created. 'Assembly-CSharp' is
>   already part of the workspace.

At the same time `.cs` stores `C#` script edit in code from `VS15` and debugs in Unity with adding to `GameObject`

Could it be by the reason that I did not installed [Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Unity](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SebastienLebreton.VisualStudio2015ToolsforUnity) `vstu2015.msi` yet, or this message comes from another reason.

I'm not sure, what I've missed, or if I'm able to accept this message above to not damage anything in VS for other not-Unity both `WPF` and `WinForms` application projects and use VS with Unity fully and successfully.

Or if I need to update VS15 IDE to [VS19](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) I'm not sure about experience on using `WinForms` support in VS19. Because experience with attempt to use VS17 few month ago resulted in   some `.olb` file problem with freezing and CPU load, just with opening of VS17 IDE without any debug or any other specific action from me. For that moment I wasn't able to solve this problem by myself or get update to fix it, so I've back to VS15

**Edit:**

I've accepted message condition with `"Change to target..."`, project loaded successfully, I can open and run updated code in Unity, but I don't have `Attach to Unity and Play` button in VS15, just `Start` which throws this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1617  Invalid option 'latest' for /langversion; must be ISO-1,
>   ISO-2, Default or an integer in range 1 to
>   6.    Assembly-CSharp C:\Users\User\Documents\New Unity Project\CSC

Any advice, guide or example would  helpful

Comment: If you install the .net frame work you will be able to use that version of VS studio, however as 2017, and 2019 are both out with a community edition which is free, upgrading is worth it.

Comment: @BugFinder Hello, I've edited my question with versions of VS15, Unity and other projects support, please check. Once I've installed VS17, and there was a problem with some `.olb` files, which projecting itself into a kind of iteration through an infinite loop, with freezing and CPU load without any action, just with opening of IDE. Maybe it was a bug with particular version of VS17, and the next update would fix it, but at that time I could not fix it by myself and returned to VS15. So, you are saying to use [VS19](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/), well I've to try

Comment: You dont have to use 2017 or even 2019 but they do come with newer useful goodies. and later .net versions get pre installed.  However, if all you had done was select that second option and install it you should have been on your merry way

Comment: @BugFinder I've added edit to my question, please check

Comment: Right, you are now trying to compile up with the wrong version.   Why didnt you do downloqd the version like suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Message is coming from another Reason. It Occures if you have another .Net Framework Version as the Version the Script is written in. If your Unity Version is 2018.1 or higher I would recommend to Install Visual Studio 2017 since they are better compatible then.
As a side Note you can Accept the Warning without fear and go on with programming but Sometimes the .sln/Connection then get's weird and you need to open Vs here and there new because of not connected Scripts.

Comment: Hello, I've edited my question with versions of VS15, Unity and other projects support, please check. As I've answered to _BugFinder_ above once I've installed VS17, and reached some `.olb` files problem with freezing and CPU load just with opening of VS17 without any action. I could not fix it and still using VS15. I guess [VS19](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/)  should not have the same problem anyway, but so far I have no good reason to update it yet, I just want try Unity. So, if I get you right, I can accept message above without fear for other projects

Comment: Yes you can Just go on with working in Vs15 if you want and accept that Message if Vs17 isn't working for you, Sorry for the Late Answer.